# Ignored exception: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in Java Applet

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, applet, invocationtargetexception

I created a Java Applet which manipulates a JSP webpage's form fields.  The JSP calls the Java Applet, of course.

This the error I'm getting in the Java Console, when I run my Java Applet on my JSP:

```
Ignored exception: java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

I am not calling InvocationTargetException or passing any exceptions in the code.  Somehow, I managed to trace it, by painstaking trial-and-error, that the line causing the error is:

```
BlowfishCBC bfcbc = new BlowfishCBC(testkey, 0, testkey.length, CBCIV_START);
```

As a test, I disabled all code that has dependencies on the JSP, so I can just run it inside Eclipse.  I created a main method to execute the Java Applet and then ran it inside Eclipse.  I got no errors or warnings, at all.

I exported the same Java Applet, as a JAR, copied it to the server, restarted Apache Tomcat, went to the page on my web browser, ran the applet, and the same InvocationTargetException error occurred

What could be the problem?

Note: I am not using try..catch anywhere in my code.  What can I put in the code that will capture this exception information and how do I do that?

Thank you.

Update:

Here is the stacktrace from the Java Console:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation.checkLiveConnectCaller(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation.access$000(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation.CallMethod(Unknown Source)
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation.checkLiveConnectCaller(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation.access$000(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation.CallMethod(Unknown Source)
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation.checkLiveConnectCaller(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation.access$000(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation.CallMethod(Unknown Source)
in encrypt method
trying to get pwd value from document
got pwd from document, password is 12345
is this getting here?
Ignored exception: java.security.PrivilegedActionException:  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

I think that's the stacktrace.  I hope that information is sufficient and helpful.

Comment: can u post your `try` `catch` block in which you have your code which gives this exception written?

Comment: Thank you.  That's the thing.  I'm not using try or catch anywhere in my code.  I am referencing a method from the BlowfishJ package, which is where the error is occurring and it's only occurring on the server.

Comment: doesn't the java console give you the whole stacktrace?

Comment: I can post the stacktrace; i set the trace level to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  It had nothing to do with the code, persay.  It was the manifest file.

Here was the manifest file, as it was originally created by Eclipse:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
```

Here it is after I modified it:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Class-Path: blowfishj.jar
```

I didn't realize that the Java Control Panel is supposed to show the blowfishj.jar file in its Resources. I see my Java Applet, there, but the blowfishj.jar file was not there, until I made the change to this manifest file.  I didn't realize it needed the manifest file.

I don't understand why it needs this in the manifest file and why this modification fixes it, though.  Maybe someone can answer that question.

Thank you.